# How can I add a variable to an array on button click?

Tags: jquery, arrays, function, variables, button

How would I add a new variable into an array each time a user clicks a button.

For example: I would have a timer and each time a user clicks a button the current time is stored in an array.

```
array[0] = 2:00; 
array[1] = 2:10; 
array[2] = 2:43;
```

This would add a new key each time the user clicks a button.

Comment: No evidence of research effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Push the new value on click:

```
$('#mybutton').click(function(){
    array.push($('#mytimer').val());
});
```

This assuming there already is an array of course named `array`.

Comment: I was just reading up on push. I have a few questions regarding jQuery arrays.
1) How would I print/alert the contents of an array to check what is being pushed into them?

2) How do I call a particular key in the array?

3) Is there any decent documentation on jQuery arrays?

Comment: jQuery is just JavaScript. The arrays are also JavaScript. And so is the push() function. So just look up the JavaScript docs for that